# Build odd and even hanoi tower

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I've got problem with hanoi tower. I know how to build normal hanoi tower, it's simple:

```
void solveTowers(char src, char dst, char mid, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    solveTowers(src, mid, dst, n - 1);
    cout << "Move " << ++counter << ": disk " << n << " from " << src << " to " << dst << endl;
    solveTowers(mid, dst, src, n - 1);
}
```

But now I want to build 2 towers:

[image]

In the first picture we've got normal hanoi tower, in the second picture is something I want to made. And now I want to have one stick(?) with only even circle and at another only odd cirle.

Could you help me?

Comment: Do you mean that the final configuration is with all even disks in one location and all odd disks in another, or do you want to say that no odd disks can ever go on the middle tower? If you impose that last restriction you won't be able to do much. The former is not too hard because that is a configuration you go through in solving one version of the towers of Hanoi puzzle going from the left location to the center.

Comment: Do you mean that the final configuration is with all even disks in one location and all odd disks in another, 
Exactly this ;)

Comment: Perhaps you can call solveTowers() multiple times, first time to move the whole tower from 1-st peg to 2-nd, second time to move 3 upper discs from the second peg to the third, third time to move 2 upper discs from 3-rd peg to 2-nd, and so on.

Comment: @DouglasZare but how to check if I have correct configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already proposed in comments you can call solveTowers() multiple times from an external function. The following code worked fine for me:

```
void solveTowers(int src, int dst, int mid, int n, vector<vector<int>>& pegs) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return;
    }
    solveTowers(src, mid, dst, n - 1, pegs);
    cout << "Moving disk " << n << " from " << src << " to " << dst << endl;
    int t = pegs[src].back();
    pegs[src].pop_back();
    pegs[dst].push_back(t);

    cout<<"pegs:\n";for(int r=0;r<pegs.size();++r){for(int c=0;c<pegs[r].size();++c)cout<<pegs[r][c]<<"\t";cout<<"\n\n";}cout<<endl;
    solveTowers(mid, dst, src, n - 1, pegs);
}

void solve_odd_even(int n) {
    vector<vector<int>> pegs(3);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        pegs[0].push_back(n - i); 
    }   
    int dst = 1;
    int mid = 2;
    if (n % 2)
        swap(dst, mid);
    solveTowers(0, dst, mid, n, pegs);
    for (int h = n - 1; h > 0; --h) {
        int src = 1;
        int dst = 2;
        if (h % 2 == 0)
            swap(src, dst);
        solveTowers(src, dst, 0, h, pegs);
    }   
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    solve_odd_even(atoi(argv[1]));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be the solution for generating your towers:

```
1234    -     -  
234     -     1
34      2     1
34      12    -
4       12    3
4       2     13
24      -     13
```

In general the hanoitower can be solved by Dijkstra's algorithm for any valid starting and endstate.

Comment: But I'd like to have algorithm for any number of circles :)

Comment: if you use dijkstra's, that's only a matter of correct implementation. if you want a specific algorithm only for the specific case with even and odd towers, i'll first have to think about a solution. Though it might be simpler to use some graph-based solution anyways.